# How do I enable iCloud syncing?

Tags: batman-arkham-city-lockdown

Version 1.1 of *Batman: Arkham City Lockdown* supposedly added iCloud syncing.  Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be enabled for me.  When I view my Documents and Data stored in iCloud, I'm not seeing any *Batman: Arkham City Lockdown* save files.

How do I enable iCloud syncing?

Comment: Do you have iCloud enabled in the first place? You can find it in the Settings app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just had to wait.  A few days after I asked this question, I noticed a little iCloud icon next to my save file and some text at the top of the screen about the game data syncing with iCloud.